# I would like to do a get method and a post method. I would like the get method to occur immediately after the Post method

Tags: c#

This is the post method.

```
   public RequirementResponseV17_01 Post(RequirementCreateRequestV17_01 request)
            {
                var result = _epicReqService.CreateMinimalRequirement(request.Model);


                return new RequirementResponseV17_01(result);
            }
```

This is the get method.

```
 public EntityResponseV16_01<IEnumerable<RequirementFieldHistory>> Get(RequirementFieldHistoryRequestV17_01 request) {
            var result = _historyService.GetRequirementHistoryEntries(request.RequirementId, request.FieldName);
            return new EntityResponseV16_01<IEnumerable<RequirementFieldHistory>>(result);
        }
```

I would like for the get method to be called immediately after the post method is called so that the history is obtained. I'm not sure how to call both at the same time and not sure if it is possible. Currently, the get method is only called when updating a field but as soon as the post method (create is done on the front-end) I would like the get method to be done.

Comment: Why not just return whatever the results are for the GET in the POST method?

Comment: why you are not calling the get from the frontend once the post is completed? what you are using for frontend. Do share the complete problem

Comment: @BrendanGreen The post method has to be done first to create the values for the Get method.